# Android change textview content

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-inflate

Hi I tried to change the content of a textview of another xml.
Unfortunaly it does not work, my code looks like this:

```
    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
    TextView testView= (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    TextView test = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById((R.id.testext));
    testView.setText("adasd");
    test.setText("adjhsajdH");
```

Does anyone know a solution.

Comment: Where is this code exactly is it in a listener

Comment: its in a if statement

Comment: Can you post the full code and have you checked if the if statement is working properly

Comment: if statements works I put a console.log

Comment: I can't help you if you didn't provide the full code and the xml files

Comment: what do you do with `inflatedView` how do you add it to your activity? post  `onCreate` and maybe `onResume`of your Activity

Answer (score 0):

When you are inflating a layout, it creates a new layout. It means your first line of code does not retrieve the layout of your fragment, but creates a new one. 
That' why you don't see the change in your fragment view.

If you want to change the values displayed by the fragment, create a new method in which fragment that will do the job internally.

Answer (score 0):

try this. remove the old layout from the parent view.

```
parentView.removeView(urtextview)
```

then add the new textview u just edited

```
parentView.add(urTextView)
```